# SQL Server PIVOT Query "Conversion Failed"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have data in this format

[image: Current Format]

And I would like in this format

```
Account AccountUnit Description  ATL  BOS   
1111      10           Trucking  23   50      
2222      13           Banking   34   21
```

I have my query as follows

```
DECLARE 
@FISCAL_YEAR AS NVARCHAR(4),
@PERIOD AS VARCHAR(2),
@COL AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COL= COALESCE (@COL+ ',','')+QUOTENAME(MX_VALUE)FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT MX_VALUE FROM AUMXVALUE WHERE MATRIX_CAT='_DIV') AS A

SET @FISCAL_YEAR = 2014
SET @PERIOD=6


SET @SQL=
N'
SELECT CURR.COMPANY, CURR.ACCT_UNIT, CURR.DESCRIPTION, CURR.ACCOUNT,
(
(SELECT UNITS.* , GLN.DESCRIPTION FROM
(SELECT 
GLU.COMPANY,
GLU.ACCT_UNIT,
GLU.ACCOUNT,
AMV.MATRIX_CAT,
'+@COL+',
CASE 
WHEN @PERIOD=1 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_01+GLU.CR_UNITS_01 
WHEN @PERIOD=2 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_02+GLU.CR_UNITS_02 
WHEN @PERIOD=3 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_03+GLU.CR_UNITS_03
WHEN @PERIOD=4 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_04+GLU.CR_UNITS_04 
WHEN @PERIOD=5 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_05+GLU.CR_UNITS_05 
WHEN @PERIOD=6 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_06+GLU.CR_UNITS_06 
WHEN @PERIOD=7 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_07+GLU.CR_UNITS_07 
WHEN @PERIOD=8 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_08+GLU.CR_UNITS_08 
WHEN @PERIOD=9 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_09+GLU.CR_UNITS_09
WHEN @PERIOD=10 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_10+GLU.CR_UNITS_10
WHEN @PERIOD=11 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_11+GLU.CR_UNITS_11 
WHEN @PERIOD=12 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_12+GLU.CR_UNITS_12 
ELSE 0 END AS ACT
FROM GLUNITS GLU JOIN GLNAMES GLN 
ON GLU.COMPANY=GLN.COMPANY
AND GLU.ACCT_UNIT='''+100+'''
JOIN AUMXVALUE AMV
ON GLN.OBJ_ID=AMV.OBJ_ID
AND AMV.MATRIX_CAT='''+'_DIV'+'''
AND GLU.FISCAL_YEAR=@FISCAL_YEAR
AND GLU.ACCOUNT=9100
)UNITS
JOIN GLNAMES GLN
ON UNITS.COMPANY=GLN.COMPANY
AND UNITS.ACCT_UNIT=GLN.ACCT_UNIT) CURR
) T PIVOT( SUM(ACT) FOR MX_VALUE IN (' + @COL + ')) AS PIVTBL'
```

```
EXEC (@SQL)
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '

SELECT CURR.COMPANY, CURR.ACCT_UNIT, CURR.DESCRIPTION, CURR.ACCOUNT,
(
(SELECT UNITS.* , GLN.DESCRIPTION FROM
(SELECT 
GLU.COMPANY,
GLU.ACCT_UNIT,
GLU.ACCOUNT,
AMV.MATRIX_CAT,
[ATL                             ],[BOS                             ]
CASE 
    WHEN @PERIOD=1 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_01+GLU.CR_UNITS_01 
    WHEN @PERIOD=2 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_02+GLU.CR_UNITS_02 
    WHEN @PERIOD=3 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_03+GLU.CR_UNITS_03
WHEN @PERIOD=4 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_04+GLU.CR_UNITS_04 
WHEN @PERIOD=5 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_05+GLU.CR_UNITS_05 
WHEN @PERIOD=6 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_06+GLU.CR_UNITS_06 
WHEN @PERIOD=7 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_07+GLU.CR_UNITS_07 
WHEN @PERIOD=8 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_08+GLU.CR_UNITS_08 
WHEN @PERIOD=9 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_09+GLU.CR_UNITS_09
WHEN @PERIOD=10 THEN GLU.DB_UNITS_10+GLU.CR_UNITS_10
WHEN @PERIOD=11 THEN GLU.DB_UNIT...
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: What do you spit out if you `print @SQL`?

Comment: Try declaring `@SQL` as `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast as `VARCHAR` the `100` as well like this:

```
...
AND GLU.ACCT_UNIT='''+CAST(100 AS VARCHAR(3))+'''
...
```

or just add it as a string like this:

```
...
AND GLU.ACCT_UNIT='''+'100'+'''
...
```